# How can I log in to DingTalk on multiple PCs at once?

Tags: chat

Is it possible to log in to DingTalk on multiple PCs at once (i.e. on my desktop AND on my laptop)?

Comment: Why are there so many downvotes on my question?

Comment: For several reasons I can guess at: this is a question best asked of this service's support and you don't indicate you've done that, this sounds like a question about a service, not software, there is no indication of any research or effort done on your part prior to asking. If you HAVE done research, show it so we know what has been learned and tried. If this is about software you've installed on your computers and the error isn't with a service, give more information. Also, read the Help section learn how this site works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to https://m.dingtalk.com/qidian/help-detail-1000105420 :

> Hello, DingTalk account supports multi-level login, such as mobile phone, computer login at the same time, but does not support multiple mobile phones or multiple computers at the same time login to the same DingTalk account.